# Visual Studio seems to show inconsistent error suggestions

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am not sure why VS code is stating that my 'from' is incorrect within my models.py file.

See image.

Is there a package or a setting that I should be aware of?

[Snip of what I am experiencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwsiz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple Python versions on your machine you might need to select the correct interpreter which the packages were installed to its  path.
Open the Command Pallet and select `Python: select interpreter` to select the correct one.

Comment: or use the bottom left item on the status bar

Comment: Thank you!! That resolved it. Appreciate your help.